# Selecting points that intersect only once?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.2, rivers

I'm working on a river layer that requires some refinements. I have attached an image for reference. I have a geofabric layer (light blue) that I have used to extract rivers with a flow >5ML/day (purple). The problem I have is that this geofabric layer is not consistent with the river layer. At some points the geofabric has touched the edges of unwanted tributaries. I have created points from the intersections (light green) and my idea is to select only the tributaries that intersect just once with the geofabric layer and cross-reference them with dangle points i have created (red cross) in order to remove them. I just can't seem to isolate the points at which they cross only once. Does anyone have any suggestions as to how I can achieve this?

River system (purple) is split at intersections.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the intersecting points were created with a tool like [Intersect](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00080000000p000000) with *join attributes* of ONLY_FID (it is imperative that the River OID/FID is recorded in the points for this method to work):

Using the tool [Summary Statistics](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00080000001z000000) with a *statistics type* of River_FID, Count and *case field* of River_FID you can obtain a list of the points representing intersections and a count of their intersections.

From this table you can [Table Select](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//000800000007000000) those with a count of 1 to reduce the number of records for the next step.

[Attribute Join](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//005s0000002q000000) the rivers to the statistics table (or selected table) then select the instances where the joined count is equal to 1. Optionally you can [make a selection layer](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s50000000p000000) then remove the join to select by location using your dangles.